# Comparing Even/Odd numbers w/ java and boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I am writing a method that takes in two numbers and will return true if they are both even or both odd... and will return false if only one is odd and one is even.
It needs to return a boolean statement, but it is not working.. Any help is appreciated! Thanks...

```
 public static boolean compareEvenOdd(int x, int y) {
            if((x % 2 ==0) && ( y% 2==0))||((x%2 != 0) && (y%2 != 0)){
                return true;
            } else
                return false;

}
```

Comment: "but it is not working" What does it do? Does it compile? On which inputs does it not work? [MCVE]

Comment: Parentheses are missing around the condition. But it could be reduced to `return (x % 2) == (y % 2)`

Comment: Check your opening/closing braces...

Comment: compareEvenOdd is a really bad name, what does true mean? They are odd they are even? Use something more meaningful compareEven(x,y) at least this way you now what true and false mean in that context. Your code works, it does not compile because of the parenthesis. @Thomas Böhm answer is really good

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following (possibly the shortest version):

```
public static boolean compareEvenOdd(int x, int y) {
    return ((x + y) % 2) == 0;
}
```

The sum of two odd numbers and the sum of two even numbers is even, the sum of one odd and one even number is odd. So you add the numbers and check if the solution is dividable by 2.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really good opportunity to use a bitwise operator.  You can use the binary AND (`&`) operator with the number `1` to reduce an integer to just its last binary digit.  This last digit is always 0 for an even number and 1 for an odd number.  If your two numbers have the same last binary digit, then they have the same parity - that is, they're both even or both odd.  So I would write the method like this.

```
public boolean sameParity(int x, int y) {
    return (x & 1) == (y & 1);
}
```

Note that the parentheses are important, because the usual Java order of operations puts `==` above `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Explication :

- `x` and `y` are odd  : `x+y` are even
- `x` and `y` are even : `x+y` are even
- `x` is odd and `y` is odd : `x+y` are odd
- `x` is even and `x` is even : `x+y` are odd

```
public static boolean compareEvenOdd(int x, int y) {
        return (x+y)%2==0
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are missing an additional pair of parentheses around the condition in the if-statement.
This works for me:

```
public static boolean compareEvenOdd(int x, int y) {
    if (((x % 2 ==0) && ( y% 2==0))||((x%2 != 0) && (y%2 != 0))){
        return true;
    } else
    return false;

}
```

if this is not to your liking, yould you further specify what is not working? Is it throwing errors as you run it, is the output wrong,...?

Answer (score 0):

- An if-statement always has the form `if (...)` with its own parentheses around the condition. Hence you missing just that.

So (with unneeded braces removed):

```
public static boolean compareEvenOdd(int x, int y) {
    if ((x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 0)
        || (x%2 != 0 && y % 2 != 0)) {
        return true;
    } else 
        return false;
}
```

And as shown in the other answers this should be simplified,
as `if+return boolean` means using boolean redundantly, not to the fullest (like `== true`):

```
    return (x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 0)
        || (x % 2 != 0 && y % 2 != 0);

    return (x % 2) == (y % 2);

    return (x - y) % 2 == 0;
```